# LaTeX CV Help with indentation

Tags: indentation, cv, date

I am having problem with the indentation in my CV. The problem is, that i want to add a second date as a newline right beneath the first one, using the \newline command just pushes the indent to the right.

I want to have it like this:

```
Summer 2017,
2016, 2015
```

Code:

```
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}

\textsc{Summer 2017 } 
& Summer Intern at \textsc{Lehman Brothers}, \emph{Capital Markets}\\
&\footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome, try a `p` column for the date as you do for the description.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Can you please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Alternative suggestion: Try a `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Summer 2017\\2016, 2015\end{tabular}`. Also a `\parbox` or a `varwidth` environment (see `varwidth` package) would be possible for example.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what you might have or want based on the question. Here is a shot into the blue.

[image: johndResumeTabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\scshape\raggedright}p{.20\linewidth}p{.75\linewidth}@{}}
    Summer 2017, 2016, \par 2015 
    & Summer Intern at \textsc{Lehman Brothers},
    \emph{Capital Markets}\par
    {\footnotesize Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics
        Trading Desk as a result of very positive review.
        Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical
    Skills and Teamwork.}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```